# TreeMap that contains String as key and a boolean as value?

Tags: java

Hello I tried to create a TreeMap in Java but the compiler gives the error saying "unexpected type".
Can anyone tell me why? Isn't possible to have primitive data types in a Map?

I did solve it by using the java.lang.Boolean instead. But I don't understand why I can't mix a complex data type with a primitive one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer your query,

Maps and other classes which are treated as collections not only serve the purpose of storing data but they also provide methods for comparing. In java comparators are used for the same. In short you need to call methods on the objects you want to compare. If the values are primitive data type, no methods can be invoked on them. This is precisely one of the major reasons why primitive data types are not permitted in collections and related classes.

hope this helps

Comment: Precisely the answer I were looking for. Thank you.

Comment: In addition, collections only contain references and there's no way to create a reference of a primitive.

Comment: @user996817 If it was "Precisely the answer" you were looking for, please give the person credit by marking it as the correct answer (use the check mark).

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't possible to have primitive data types in a Map?

No, it isn't.  Try `<String, Boolean>`.

Answer (score 1):

> But I don't understand why I can't mix a complex data type with a primitive one.

It's not about mixing complex data types with the primitive types.

The reason is that none of the classes in the Java Collection Framework are designed to support primitive types.

If you need to use any primitive type with the collection framework then you have to use the corresponding wrapper class. e.g. `Integer` for `int` ...

Only array supports primitive types.

Answer (score 0):

> Isn't possible to have primitive data types in a Map?

No.  You cannot use primitive types at all in Java generics.